# Text processing - Split the first column into two columns based on a character

Tags: shell, awk, sed, text-processing, cut

Split the first column in the file into two columns based on a character.
The data inside the brackets () should be moved to the new column removing the brackets.

Given csv file:

```
Col1(col2),col3,col4,col5
a(23),12,test(1),test2
b(30),15,test1(2),test3
```

Expected File:

```
Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
a,23,12,test(1),test2
b,30,15,test1(2),test3
```

I tried the below code. I am not able to extract data between the brackets and also it takes every occurence of "()".

```
awk -F"(" '$1=$1' OFS="," filename
```

Comment: `awk -F"[(),]+" '$1=$1' OFS="," file`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew only use the result of an action as a condition when you **need** to otherwise you're obfuscating the code and introducing potential bugs. In this case, for example, your script would fail when `$1` is `0` - write `{$1=$1}1` instead of just `$1=$1`.

Comment: @EdMorton I did not write it :) It is copy/paste.  I focused on the field separator pattern only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it wasn't obvious to me that you weren't suggesting a complete solution so the OP may not have realized that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your pick:

```
$ sed 's/(\([^)]*\))/,\1/' file
Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
a,23,12,test(1),test2
b,30,15,test1(2),test3

$ sed 's/(/,/; s/)//' file
Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
a,23,12,test(1),test2
b,30,15,test1(2),test3
```

.

```
$ awk '{sub(/\(/,","); sub(/\)/,"")} 1' file
Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
a,23,12,test(1),test2
b,30,15,test1(2),test3

$ awk 'match($0,/\([^)]*\)/){$0= substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "," substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) } 1' file
Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
a,23,12,test(1),test2
b,30,15,test1(2),test3

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} split($1,a,/[()]/) > 1{$1=a[1] "," a[2]} 1' file
Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
a,23,12,test(1),test2
b,30,15,test1(2),test3

$ gawk '{$0=gensub(/\(([^)]*)\)/,",\\1",1)} 1' file
Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
a,23,12,test(1),test2
b,30,15,test1(2),test3

$ gawk 'match($0,/([^(]*)\(([^)]*)\)(.*)/,a){$0=a[1] "," a[2] a[3]} 1' file
Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
a,23,12,test(1),test2
b,30,15,test1(2),test3
```

Those last 2 require GNU awk for gensub() and the 3rd arg to match() respectively. There are alternatives too.

Comment: You could greatly improve your answer if you explained each of the solutions. Code only answers are not that valuable to SO community.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I completely disagree. The OP will learn far more by looking up the man page to understand these trivial scripts than if I write an explanation for each of them. Teach a man to fish...

Answer (score 0):

For completeness...

**posix shell**

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    car=${line%%)*}
    caar=${car%%(*}
    cdar=${car##*(}
    cdr=${line#*)}
    printf '%s\n' "$caar,$cdar$cdr"
done < file
```

---

I don't think you can solve using `cut` alone.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try 1 more `sed` solution, which may help you.

```
sed 's/\([^(]*\)(\([^)]*\))\(.*\)/\1,\2\3/'  Input_file
```